# any way to vectorize the input into sgdclassifier?

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp, vectorization

I have a featureset for each token of the input, e.g. {'ft1': 'something', 'ft2':102} for a token. I need to vectorized it and pass into sklearn's SGDClassifier.

I tried to use sklearn.DictVectorizer, but the problem is the dataset is huge, so it's impossible to fit_transform them all. I have to do batches and partial_fit to SGDClassifier. Thus, if i fit_transform on each batch of the input, the size of the vectors are going to be different, so that they can't be used for partial_fit to the same classifier.

Any advice on this? How can I vectorize the inputs with fixed size? Thank you!

Comment: Try https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.html

Comment: It seems that the input is a list of strings instead of feature sets... Any way to vectorized feature sets?

Comment: I showed you a way to vectorize features in one pass, if you have memory restrictions. If you need more than that, you have to update your question with a representative excerpt of your data